# Is "Send To > Compressed Folder" available in XP + Vista + 7?

Tags: windows, zip, user-interface

I need to write a document that explains to non-techies how to zip a bunch of files.

Unless there's a better way, I'll use Windows' internal "Send To" option.

However, users might be running XP, Vista, or 7.

Does someone know if this item is available in the pop-up menu in all three versions, and labeled the same way?

In addition, since the "My computer" icon is not displayed by default, what would be the easiest way for a non-power user to navigate to a given folder/directory?

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe the "Send To" menu does have "Compressed (Zip) Folder" on all versions of Windows since Windows XP.  It is visible on my Vista machine, and I'm sure I have seen it on Windows 7.  The name should be similar (if not the same) on all versions.

XP:

[image]

Vista:

[image]

Windows 7:

[image]

As to navigating to a particular folder the hotkey <kbd>Win</kbd>+<kbd>E</kbd> will open an Explorer window that (I believe) will always open at the "My Computer" area so you could use that as a starting point.

Comment: Thanks, I didn't think about using the Windows button.

Answer (score 0):

Send to compressed is available as a popup option in XP, Vista and 7.  In some cases it may not be installed under a specific user profile.